# optimize javafx code consuming large amount of memory and CPU

Tags: image, split, grid, javafx, imageview

the code below is for a fundraiser dinner to purchase a land, the purpose is to show the progress of the square meter of land purchased (around 2976m2). everytime a square meter is purchased, the application adds an image tile which corresponds to an acctual 1m2. eventually the tiles (~2976 of them) fill up like in a grid to complete the land once fully purchased.

The size of each tiles is around 320bytes, there are 2976 tiles in total.

I have also showing below an image example.

[image]

The thing that drives me crazy with this code (in javafx) is that it consumes around 90 to 100% of 1 of my processors and the memory usage keeps increasing as the tiles add up until the code buffer run out of memory and the program crashes after a while. this is not desirable during the fundraising dinner.

the full code is available for testing at 
you will need to change boolean split to true false, which will split the images for you, (around 3000 images);

https://github.com/rihani/Condel-Park-Fundraiser/tree/master/src/javafxapplication3

The main culprit that uses all the memory and CPU is the AnimationTimer() function shown below and I am wondering if anyone can help me reduce memory and CPU usage in this code.

to briefly explain how the code below is used, the land is divided into 2 panes, when the first one grid_pane1 is filled up the second pane grid_pane2 starts to then fill up.
also a flashing tile is used to show the current progress.

I am using total_donnation ++; to test the code, but would normally use mysql to pull the new value raised during the findraising dinner

AnimationTimer() Code:

```
translate_timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override public void handle(long now) {
                if (now > translate_lastTimerCall + 10000_000_000l) 
                {
                    old_total_donnation = total_donnation;
                    try 
                    {
//                        c = DBConnect.connect();
//                        SQL = "Select * from donations";
//                        rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);
//                        while (rs.next()) 
//                        {total_donnation = rs.getInt("total_donnation");}
//                        c.close();

                        total_donnation ++;

                        if(total_donnation != old_total_donnation)
                        {
                            System.out.format("Total Donation: %s \n", total_donnation);

                            old_total_donnation = total_donnation;
                            if (!pane1_full)
                            {
                                grid_pane1.getChildren().clear();
                                grid_pane1.getChildren().removeAll(imageview_tile1,hBox_outter_last);                                
                            }
                            grid_pane2.getChildren().clear();
                            grid_pane2.getChildren().removeAll(imageview_tile2,hBox_outter_last);

                            for(i=0; i<=total_donnation; i++)
                            {
                                if (pane1_full){  System.out.println("Pane 1 has not been redrawn"); break;}
                                file1 = new File("pane1_img"+i+".png");
                                pane1_tiled_image = new Image(file1.toURI().toString(),image_Width,image_Height,false,false);
                                imageview_tile1 = new ImageView(pane1_tiled_image);
                                grid_pane1.add(imageview_tile1, current_column_pane1,current_row_pane1);   
                                current_column_pane1 = current_column_pane1+1;
                                if (current_column_pane1 == max_columns_pane1 )
                                {
                                    current_row_pane1 = current_row_pane1+1;
                                    current_column_pane1 = 0;
                                }
                                if (i == max_donnation_pane1 ){ pane1_full = true; System.out.println("Pane 1 full"); break;}
                                if (i == total_donnation)
                                {
                                    if (i != max_donnation_pane1)
                                    {

                                        hBox_outter_last = new HBox();
                                        hBox_outter_last.setStyle(style_outter);
                                        hBox_outter_last.getChildren().add(blink_image);

                                        ft1 = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(500), hBox_outter_last);
                                        ft1.setFromValue(1.0);
                                        ft1.setToValue(0.3);
                                        ft1.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
                                        ft1.setAutoReverse(true);
                                        ft1.play();
                                        grid_pane1.add(hBox_outter_last, current_column_pane1,current_row_pane1);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            if (i < total_donnation)
                            {
                                total_donnation_left = total_donnation - max_donnation_pane1;
                                for(j=0; j<=total_donnation_left; j++)
                                {
                                    file2 = new File("pane2_img"+j+".png");
                                    pane2_tiled_image = new Image(file2.toURI().toString(),image_Width,image_Height,false,false);
                                    imageview_tile2 = new ImageView(pane2_tiled_image);
                                    grid_pane2.add(imageview_tile2, current_column_pane2,current_row_pane2);       
                                    current_column_pane2 = current_column_pane2+1;
                                    if (current_column_pane2 == max_columns_pane2 )
                                    {
                                        current_row_pane2 = current_row_pane2+1;
                                        current_column_pane2 = 0;
                                    }
                                    if (j == max_donnation_pane2 ){ System.out.println("Pane 2 full"); break;}
                                    if (j == total_donnation_left)
                                    {
                                        if (j != max_donnation_pane2)
                                        {
                                            hBox_outter_last = new HBox();
                                            hBox_outter_last.setStyle(style_outter);
                                            hBox_outter_last.getChildren().add(blink_image);

                                            ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(500), hBox_outter_last);
                                            ft.setFromValue(1.0);
                                            ft.setToValue(0.3);
                                            ft.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
                                            ft.setAutoReverse(true);
                                            ft.play();

                                            grid_pane2.add(hBox_outter_last, current_column_pane2,current_row_pane2);
                                        }
                                    }  
                                }
                            }  
                            current_column_pane1 =0;
                            current_row_pane1=0;
                            current_column_pane2=0;
                            current_row_pane2=0;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {}
                    translate_lastTimerCall = now;

                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First and foremost, you create a lot of indefinite `FadeTransitions` that are never stopped. These add up over time and cause both memory and CPU leaks. You should `stop()` the transition before starting a new one. Alternatively, you only need one transition to interpolate the value of a `DoubleProperty` and then bind node's opacity to this property:

   ```
   DoubleProperty opacity = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
   Transition opacityTransition = new Transition() {
       protected void interpolate(double frac) {
           opacity.set(frac);
       }
   };

   // elsewhere
   hBox_outter_last.opacityProperty().bind(opacity);
   ```
2. You may want to preload all the image tiles beforehand, so that you avoid reading from disk in the loop.
3. You unnecessarily destroy and recreate large part of the scene in every cycle. You should modify your code to only add the new tiles and not drop them all and recreate them from scratch.
4. Finally, when you actually query the database, you should do it from a different thread and not the JavaFX application thread, because your UI will be unresponsive for the time of the query (e.g. not animating your fade transitions).

Comment: Thanks Tomas. Any idea how to go about stopping the fade transitions. I tried .stop but doesn't do anything maybe I am not putting it at the correct place.

Comment: I have used a mechanism where only the new tiles are oases. But it was as well using high CPU and memory.

Comment: Try putting `if(ft != null) { ft.stop(); }` right before `ft = new FadeTransition(...);`. The same for `ft1`. Also, what JavaFX version do you use? I think there used to be a bug with not releasing the animations, which should now be fixed. Alternatively, you only need one animation that animates a `DoubleProperty` and then bind node's opacity to this one property.

Comment: Thanks. You are talking way past my level re binding. Would Welcome an example.

Comment: the culprit for CPU usage is the fade transition, if I remove it, CPU usage goes down to 6%!! would really appreciate help with this, by the way the if(ft != null) { ft.stop(); } does not do anything

Comment: See my updated answer. One fade transition is cheap. The problem is that you create so many of them. Did you do the same for `ft1` and didn't observe any improvement? What JavaFX version are you running?

Comment: javafx version is 1.8.0_05

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion:

- Do not split the image instead using 2 panels. One for displaying the whole image. The second will be a grid pane overlapping the first pane. Therefore, when a square meter is purchased, the background of corresponding grid-cell will become transparent.

Comment: I like that thought. Will give a try. I only have 1 day left :)